# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'scriptsFailed' of undefined

Tags: ajax

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'scriptsFailed' of undefined error in script manager.
Pls suggest solution for this.
Thanks in Advance.

**Error Message** :

[image]

Comment: Pls open this link for more details
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sejq6.png

Comment: Hardly can't answer to your question if you don't post you javascript code!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: With below ScriptManager my site was working in HTTP.
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smEkstopMaster" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"  EnableCdn="true" >
Recently we added SSL certificate, EnableCdn="true" was loding HTTP Ajax scripts insted of HTTPS.

Comment: So i cahnged my scriptmager like below.
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smEkstopMaster" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" >
<Scripts><asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" Path="~/Javascripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" Path="~/Javascripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" /></Scripts></asp:ScriptManager>
It worked fine for some pages but in checkout page its giving error [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sejq6.png)

Comment: When add EnablePartialRendering="false" then it didnt give error in check out page , giving error in other pages.Please provide proper solution for this.